# Swift frame update causes wrong layout update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

Scenario: I have a webview on fullscreen that needs to shrink from the top to make room for another view that can be toggled to show or hide. That view is always of 160 height

this is my code for shrinking the webview

It causes the webview to have a wrong final size even though i set the exact CGRect on it

```swift
@objc func setLayout(){
    let insets = self.view.safeAreaInsets

    self.insetTop = insets.top
    self.insetBottom = insets.bottom
    self.totalHeight = self.view.frame.height + insets.top

    self.webViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.webViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 - self.insetTop, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.totalHeight)

    self.callViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.callViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 160)

    print("init webview frame")
    print(self.webViewController.view.frame)
    perform(#selector(simulateShow), with: nil, afterDelay: 4)
    perform(#selector(simulateHide), with: nil, afterDelay: 6)
    perform(#selector(simulateShow), with: nil, afterDelay: 8)
    perform(#selector(simulateHide), with: nil, afterDelay: 10)
}

@objc func simulateShow(){
    print("init webview show")
    var yy: CGFloat = 100

    self.webViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yy, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.totalHeight - 160)
    print(self.webViewController.view.frame)
}
@objc func simulateHide(){
    print("init webview hide")
    self.webViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 - self.insetTop, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.totalHeight)
    print(self.webViewController.view.frame)
}
```

youtube link for simulator output [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xv0YQqaBvM&feature=youtu.be)

xcode debug output

```
init webview frame
(0.0, -44.0, 375.0, 856.0)
init webview show
(0.0, 100.0, 375.0, 696.0)
init webview hide
(0.0, -44.0, 375.0, 856.0)
init webview show
(0.0, 100.0, 375.0, 696.0)
init webview hide
(0.0, -44.0, 375.0, 856.0)
```

I've added .edgesIgnoringSafeArea to SceneDelegate.swift

```
let contentView = ContentView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Comment: Are you using constraints?

Comment: @John - I don't see anything wrong with what's happening. You're setting the `totalHeight` property as a variable of your view's height, which is fixed. When you call `simulateShow()`, you're resetting the `CGRect` height to `totalHeight - 160`, so whenever you call this method it's shrinking the height by 160 which is reflected in your output (696.0 = 856-160).

Comment: @Pierce yes. and after that i call simulateHide() which should revert things because I am setting the same frame values as the first time. But as you can see in the youtube link, the layout is wrong after calling simulateHide()

Comment: @John - What I'm saying is that it doesn't look like the height is the problem, it's the positioning on the y-axis. FYI - this is a perfect example of when using constraints for dynamic UI is much better than static UI using frames.

Comment: @Pierce . from the youtube clip, both y and height are wrong. the height is bigger and the Y is further upwards. I'm creating those views programatically so I'm not sure how to proceed further. I also need to go outside of the safeArea with those views

Comment: @John - the height is not wrong. It's exactly as it should be based on your code. When you call `simulateShow` you're setting the height to `totalHeight - 160`, so when it's first laid out it'll be 856 and any time that `simulateShow` is called it'll reduce by 160 to 696 which is exactly what you're seeing. Also why are you setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false? This shouldn't be necessary since you're not using constraints. It seems to me like this is more of an issue with the safeArea changing.

Comment: @Pierce . judging by the log, the height and position is always right. but visually is not. check the youtube link please. the final height(all light gray space) is bigger than initial. Also, do you have any suggestion as to how to achieve what I want?

Comment: @John - I watched the video and it's actually not bigger than what it is initially, it's only appearing that way, because it's yMin point is extended 44.0 points above the top of the screen (which is also why it's appearing off the screen and printing out -44.0). Your best bet to get rid of this is to use constraints and forget about having to calculate frame changes. (See Next comment for more)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205000/discussion-between-john-and-pierce).

Comment: If you set your callView or whatever it's called as having it's top constraint attached to the top of the SafeArea with a height of 0.0 it'll be invisible, then you can make your webViewController's top constraint set to the bottom of the call view, and then if you animate the height change for your callView, the position of the webViewController will move down as it's dynamically set to being constrained to the bottom of the CallView. So the CallView would animate and at the same time the webViewController will animate downwards.

Comment: @Pierce let's continue this in chat please